# Tree-based machine learning algorithms and qualitative predictors with a lot of unordered categories

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, random-forest

As far as I understood, tree-based methods are based on yes/no questions that refer to single predictors. E.g. is predictor A larger than 3000 or is predictor B = "TRUE".

In case you have a qualitative predictor that has more than two categories, trees have to generate dummy-variables or rather dummy logical questions. The number of dummy variables / questions being the number of categories - 1.

E.g. when you have a predictor C that is composed of the categories "red", "blue", "yellow", you might find the following logical questions in your tree: "is C = red? yes or no" and "is C = blue? yes or no". In order to correctly identify the color of an object, you would have to ask a maximum of two binary questions.

Now, I often have data where you have 35 or even more categories. Therefore, the tree can ask 34 (or even more) logical questions that only relate to a particular predictor.

When using a random forest, you randomly select a subset of available predictor variables per decision tree.

Let's say, you have 1 qualitative predictor with 35 categories and 5 quantitative predictors. The tree will consider 34 dummy variables plus the 5 quantitative ones.

If you randomy choose 10 variables per tree, there is a super high chance that you will only end up with the dummy variables and the tree will overrepresent the qualitative predictor.

Are tree-based methods therefore unfit for handling data that is composed of qualitative predictors exhibiting a lot of categories?

Or did I miss something?

I would really like to read your input regarding to this question.

Comment: To be honest it depends the implementation of your tree. It depends which measure is used to split the tree. According to my knowledge, in sklearn, it does not handle categorical feature (directly, you can one hot encode or do what you want to handle that). If you use one hot encoding (as you propose here), it makes your "categorical " dimension very big compared to your "continuous" dimension and it could be a bad idea whatever is the model. Categorical embedding is a complex problem and have only (at least for the moment) local solutions (by model and dataset).

Comment: So what would be a different way to encode qualitative variables in tree-based methods?

Comment: It depends greatly of your goal. You can try [mean encoding](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-try-mean-encoding-17057262cd0), or embedding of any sort (like [google bert](https://pypi.org/project/bert-embedding/) is done for nlp (what i mean by that is, there is as much way of "encode" you categorical data than there is matrix at least since you can for example multiply your one hot encode vector by any matrix of right size to go in any dimension). I don't have answer, that's why i comment :D

Comment: Some implementations of tree-based methods do not need the OHE of the categorical feature. Instead, they sort the categories based on some metric (e.g. mean target value) and then use all the categories for a split.